# execute a function in a viewmodel and real time refresh of the view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a small problem with my MVVM application.

I have a function in a viewmodel which modify a collection. This collection is bind to the view to show a datagrid. When an user click on a button, the function modify the collection but it can take few minutes and the view is not refresh.

My question is how can I execute this function to have the view refreshed in real time ?

In another program I have used the dispatcher but it was in the code behind of the view without binding.

Thanks

Edit :

Model :

```
public class Composants : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _nom;

    public string Nom
    {
        get { return _nom; }
        set { _nom = value; OnPropertyChanged("Nom"); }
    }

}
```

ViewModel :

```
public class PageSynchroViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void SynchroniserComposants()
    {
        foreach (var comp in _selectedVersion.ListeComposants)
        {
            comp.Nom = "";
        }
}
```

View (I don't put all the code):

```
<Page x:Class="Centre_de_synchronisation.Vues.PageSynchro"
  [...]
  xmlns:app="clr-namespace:Centre_de_synchronisation.Classes" mc:Ignorable="d"
  d:DesignHeight="531" d:DesignWidth="778"
Title="PageSynchro" Background="{x:Null}">
<Canvas>
    [...]
    <DataGrid Name="GridComposants" Style="{StaticResource DatagridStyle}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListeComposants}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="201" Height="285"  Width="754"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
       Header="Nom"
       Binding="{Binding Nom}"
       Width="150"
               IsReadOnly="True"/>
            [...]
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Name="BoutonSynchro" Style="{StaticResource MessageBoxButtonStyle}" Content="Synchroniser" Height="27" Width="107" Command="{Binding BoutonSynchro}" CommandParameter="GridComposants" Visibility="{Binding Etat, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: A few *minutes*? Can you post your code?

Comment: few seconds but user don't have any information when he click on "Synchro" button. I have a small loading indicator on the MainWindow. When user click on synchro button, PageSynchroViewModel send a message to the MainWindow (with mvvm light) to show loading indicator but it doesn't display.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of the collection you are using now.

This should cause the View to be updated whenever an Item is added or removed from the collection.

Just remember when interacted with the `ObservableCollection` to Invoke the Dispatcher otherwise you will get Thread Access Exceptions

Here is the code I did to test this.

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <loc:MyViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Canvas DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
              Width="150"
              Height="200">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom"
                                Binding="{Binding Nom}"
                                Width="150"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Command="{Binding DoStuffCommand}"
            Canvas.Bottom="0"
            Canvas.Right="0">Stuff</Button>
</Canvas>
```

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Collection { get; set; }

    public ICommand DoStuffCommand { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Collection.Add(new MyModel { Nom = i.ToString() });
        }

        this.DoStuffCommand = new RelayCommand(DoStuff);
    }

    private void DoStuff()
    {
        foreach (var item in Collection)
        {
            item.Nom = item.Nom + ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string nom;

    public string Nom
    {
        get { return nom; }
        set
        {
            nom = value;
            RaiseChanged("Nom");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaiseChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

It updated the Nom in the view.

Comment: I not add or remove items, just change items property, and every property call propertyChanged events. The model that I use for the collection implement INotifyPropertyChange

Comment: At the end of processing try invoking the `PropertyChanged` event with the name of the collection, if you are using `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the collection items they should bubble up through the `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Should be occurring in your view model. Although you may wish to update your question with relevant code. It will probably attract more answers.

Comment: You'll need to register the `PropertyChanged` event on each item you're adding to your `ObservableCollection` :)

Comment: @user1069516 I've updated my answer with some code, you may see what you've missed.

Comment: thanks for your code ywm but it not changes anything of what I do. The collection named "_selectedVersion.ListeComposants" is instantiated on the beginning. When user click on "synchronise", neither items are added nor deleted to this collection, just an update of some properties. Binding works perfectly but I have visual results only at the end of the function and not during execution. When an item property is modified, propertyChange event is correctly raised but display is not refreshed

Comment: It sounds like in that case, the method you are calling to update the collection is blocking the UI thread. That would explain why it doesn't update the View until the method returns and frees up the UI thread.

Comment: I totally agree with you but is there a solution ?